# Proper type of adhesive for reattaching mouse feet

Tags: mouse, logitech-mouse

If the four small pieces of thin black plastic at the bottom of a mouse have been detached and I need to reattach them, what type of adhesive am I supposed to use?

[image]

Comment: I had a macabre vision of you trying to stick legs back legless mice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They use the conventional, flat (not foam based) double sided tape from what I've seen. Just make sure both sides are *completely* clean, and *carefully* cut to shape.